# PHP MySQL table data to accordion

Tags: php, css, mysql, html

I have a page where i want it to display the data of a database table in accordion's while having some buttons to edit the data displayed on the accordion. Initially i tried to display the accordions but when clicking on them only the 1st accordion collapses.

Here's the code i currently have:

```
<?php

    $sql = "SELECT nopId, studentname, studentcourse FROM nopforms";
    $result = $con->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $studentname = $row["studentname"];
            $studentcourse = $row["studentcourse"];
            echo "<div class='pnel-group' id='accordion'>
                    <div class='panel panel-default'>
                    <div class='panel-heading'>
                    <h4 class='panel-title'>
                    <a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion' href='#collapse1'>".$studentname."</a>
                        </h4>
                        </div>
                         <div id='collapse1' class='panel-collapse collapse'>
                            <div class='panel-body'>".$studentcourse."</div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
            ";
            }
    } else {
    echo "You have not submitted any logs!";
    }




    ?>
```

Html code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1"><?php echo $row["studentname"]; ?></a>
            </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
            </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You're missing a closing `</div>` tag.

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: It wasn't an answer, I was just letting you know you'd missed it. :)

Comment: An html `id` should be unique in the page, hardly possible if you put that into a loop.

Comment: Where in the html code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments above, you need a unique id for each accordion, or else they will all point to the same element.

You could change your code as follows:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT nopId, studentname, studentcourse FROM nopforms";
$result = $con->query($sql);

$i = 0; 
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $i++;
        $studentname = $row["studentname"];
        $studentcourse = $row["studentcourse"];
        echo "
            <div class='pnel-group' id='accordion".$i."'>
                <div class='panel panel-default'>
                    <div class='panel-heading'>
                        <h4 class='panel-title'>
                            <a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion".$i."' 
                                    href='#collapse".$i."'>"
                                .$studentname."
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id='collapse".$i."' class='panel-collapse collapse'>
                        <div class='panel-body'>".$studentcourse."</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ";
    }
} else {
echo "You have not submitted any logs!";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, that seems to be working, do you believe it will be possible to place buttons within each accordion to manipulate the data within ?

Comment: It certainly should be possible. However, in order to refresh the data between the accordion list elements, I think a lot would depend on your desired user experience. If you wish to refresh the data in-place, without reloading the page, then some jQuery code will have to be written. If you want the user to be taken to a new page upon clicking the button, then an `<a>` tag could be created with the button's display class and the URL parameter being the `id` of the record passed as a reference to the new page.

Comment: and if i want to add a search bar to display specified accordions with the search parameters ?

Comment: Do you mean something like a filter that will hide the accordion list elements if they don't match the search criteria (please correct me if I'm wrong)? jQuery is what you will need for that too.

Comment: Yup exactly what you described, when the user presses the search button it will hide the already displayed elements and display accordions based on the criteria.

Comment: I don't have a sample right now relevant to Bootstrap framework (which I think you're using), but a quick search led me to a [jQuery plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/accordion/Sortable-Filterable-jQuery-Accordion-Plugin-AccordionList.html). Please check the demo of it. Even though the code for bootstrap will be somewhat different, it could probably give you a bit of a kickstart on how to go about this.